# .trigger('change') sometimes not work in change select value

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, triggers

I have some select input that depends to each other.
I want to select them with a session data of user authentication respectively.
That's OK and works fine. But Sometimes trigger not work, don't select any option.
In console all of the select values are correct and show them but don't select them in inputs.
Does any one know the reason?

```
    var req = new RequestManager({
        route: '/organization/session/',
        type: 'GET',
        onSuccess: function (result) {
            console.log(result.is_school,'select school',result);
            if( result.is_school === true) {
                $('#organization').val(result.id);
                $('#organization').trigger('change');

                 $('#educational_branch_id').val(result.id);
                 $('#educational_branch_id').trigger('change');

                 if(result.elementary === true) {
                    $('#educational_section_id').val(result.section_id);
                    $('#educational_section_id').trigger('change');
                 }
            }
        }
    });
    req.send();
```

Comment: Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button; [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/)).

Answer (score 0):

instead of using

```
 $('#organization').val(result.id);
```

Use

```
$('#organization option[value='+result.id+']').attr('selected', true);
```

for `select` for making the value selected.

Comment: thanks for your response but that not work. that's like my code sometimes don't select input value.

Comment: @zahra please include your html too above. will do it

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following method to `trigger` change after adding the `val()`

```
var req = new RequestManager({
        route: '/organization/session/',
        type: 'GET',
        onSuccess: function (result) {
            console.log(result.is_school,'select school',result);
            if( result.is_school === true) {
                $('#organization').val(result.id).trigger('change');


                 $('#educational_branch_id').val(result.id).trigger('change');


                 if(result.elementary === true) {
                    $('#educational_section_id').val(result.section_id).trigger('change');

                 }
            }
        }
    });
    req.send();
```

You can use two way to trigger change after adding value

```
1) $('#educational_section_id').val(result.section_id).trigger('change');
```

**OR**

```
2) $('#educational_section_id').val(result.section_id).change();
```

Comment: Please give the reason behind downvoted . Be gentleman in gentlemen's community please  :(

Comment: Yeah there is somebody who doesn't even check and downvoting without explaining the reason .

Comment: Hope the community will look after this . And the moderators of the community must have to concern about this things . @NijinKoderi .

Comment: thanks for your response but also this way don't work :( .. when i refresh the page sometimes doesn't select the vals!!

Comment: yes. tried both the ways. that's OK.. but when i reload the page for several times ; sometimes don't work.